# Directsound playing captured audio

Tags: .net, directsound

I'm trying to work out a simple DirectSound app, but the lack of .net documentation has me frustrated.

I'd like to capture the audio from one device and play it back to another. (like an audio repeater) I've got the capture part, but I don't know how to send the capturebuffer out to a secondarybuffer.

Does anyone know of a .net example out there?

Answer (score 1):

You better off writing this in `DirectShow` using [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/).
IT should be not more then 20 lines of code writing this under DirectShow, basically you create a graph which start with the microphone and ends in the output device.